# What is the difference between `update` and `upgrade`

Tags: terminology, deployment, software-updates

What is the difference between `update` and `upgrade` in the context of application software?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Depends entirely on the installation technology, company developing the software and the whim of the person using the terms.  Generally though, updates stay within a product version (for example, hotfixes), while if you want to move to a later version, you would *upgrade*.

So you might install an update (hotfix) for Office 2007, or you might upgrade to Office 2010.

This page gives the definition according to Windows Installer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 19):

For better understanding of something that is complicated, just make it more simplier.
In this example, just split the word into atoms, like these:

- Update - UP_DATE - make it up to date;
- Upgrade - UP_GRADE - move it to the upper (or next) grade (or level).

Answer (score 6):

When I think of *update*, I think of something *free*.

When I think of *upgrade*, I think of something that *costs*.

But of course, it just really depends on the software. I've seen the terminology used interchangeably before.

Comment: good point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your service contract, the cost.

Answer (score 1):

Consider thinking about it this way:

An update is taking something you have and tweaking it a bit, usually to fix something that someone found broken.  Quite often the vendor feels obligated to give this for free, since it's what you should have gotten, how it was advertised, or secures something better.  Occasionally little improvements and optimizations are delivered as well.

An upgrade is getting the next best thing, which usually is new behavior, features, or compatability.  The new software will have noticable functional improvements or additions.

Answer (score -1):

**Update** - This is simply adding the new modified files in a small scale, but will have the originality with new additions to it.

Ex: updating the Virus Definition in your Antivirus

**Upgrade** - This is promoting from one level to another level, sometimes the out put product can be a totally changed version of the original which was existing earlier

Ex: Upgrading windows 98 to Windows XP